# How to detect and extract variables from angular html template using AST?

Tags: javascript, angular, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a project written in Angular (html+typescript).

I want to get all the variables inside the HTML template of each component. for example I have HTML component looks like that:

```
<div *ngIf="value === true">{{ foo }}</div>
```

So my variables are `value` and `foo`.

Is it possible to parse the angular template and detect those variables using some AST tool?

I tried to use `@angular/compiler` library but how to find the variables inside this AST? i searched deep inside that object but I could not find any indication of "it's variable".

[stackblitz.com](http://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dqsq5w?file=index.ts)

Comment: Why not use the Angular compiler? https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/main/packages/compiler

Comment: I tried it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dqsq5w?file=index.ts
but how to find the variables inside this AST? i searched deep inside that object but I could not find any indication of "it's variable"

Comment: Here's a good place to start: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/compiler/src/expression_parser/parser.ts#L232. Compilers are incredibly complex and take time to learn, so you may have trouble finding an answer to this question from anyone but those who have worked on this specific compiler. It couldn't hurt to open an issue on the repo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to retrive the variables, you'll have to navigate through the AST (recursively).

For your example you'll get your variables with :

```
ast.nodes[0].attributes[0].name
```

and

```
ast.nodes[0].children[0].value.ast.expressions[0].name
```